# Play 1.2.4.3: How to find currently used port for debugger?

Tags: eclipse, playframework, playframework-1.x

I have several Play applications running parallel. One of them is running in Eclipse. I want to connect the Eclipse debugger (launcher "Connect JPDA to myapplication.launch"), but the port changes every time (probably due to one of the other applications blocking the default port). I would edit the launcher and enter the current port manually*, but: How would I know which port to use?

PS: As my app runs for quite a while I do not see the port initially displayed in the console anymore.

*PPS: Is there a more elegant way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, in OS X you'll find the port in the activity monitor: Double click each "java" process until you find the one belonging to Eclipse. The requested port is the one mapped to "*".

Click [here](http://blog.crusy.net/2014/12/18/eclipse-jpda-port-nachtraeglich-herausfinden/) for details (in German) and screenshots (I need 10 reputation to post images or more than two links)

Answer (score 1):

The more elegant way of handling this is to just define the jpda port it should use yourself, so you always know behind which jpda port an application is running and you don't have to look it up all the time. Its documented in [the configuration manual](https://playframework.com/documentation/1.2.x/configuration#jpda) and it comes down to adding `jpda.port=????` in your `application.conf` (changing the question marks into a port number, ofcourse).

The reason they change is indeed because they are running in parallel. Java automatically switches to the next available port if the default is in use.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a line in the output log that looks like the following:

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: <some port number>
```

That's the debug port number you need to configure in Eclipse for JPDA.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But this line is at the top of the output and after a while I cannot see the line anymore – or ist there a file Play is logging to, besides the console output?

Comment: You can configure Play to log to a file. Have a look at the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.x/logs), specifically the "Configure log levels" section, for details.

Comment: Ah, good to know, thanks. I will configure my app, but for now I needed a way to find the port without restarting the server, as I would loose my in-memory database

Comment: You know you can load data when Play starts up right? Have a look [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.5/yaml), specifically the "Loading the data structure in your application" section.

If you really don't want to use the in-memory database you could just change the database url in your application.conf to: test.db.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/mydata